# Notation: density

Tags: notation

I know that $B \subset \bar{A}$ means that  *$A$ is dense in $B$*.

Is there a symbol that can be used between $A$ (not $\bar{A}$) and $B$ to state the same thing?

Comment: $(B\setminus A)^\circ=\emptyset$ might be another possibilty, but I don't see it being more effective... I personally like to write in down in words. But to answer your question more directly: no, I do not know any such symbol.

Comment: What about $int(B$\A$)=\emptyset$ ? At least for metric spaces i think it works.